# high charts: in bar labels only showing on some bars

Tags: highcharts, jscript

using HighChart bar chart. aiming for big font labels on the bars

have increased font size in the datalabels.style.fontSize = 50

but labels only show in 2 of the right hand columns!

making font smaller (e.g. 30) it only shows in one bar... weird!

http://jsfiddle.net/py6txbr9/57/

```
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
```

welcome any thoughts if this is happened to anyone else - can't find any bugs or issues else where.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaulty databales are printed "above" column, so when you set white color, there are "invisible". The solution is set "inside" flag as true and verticalAlign as top

```
dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    verticalAlign:'top',
                    inside:true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/py6txbr9/59/

Comment: always the simple things!